# Joining Two Polylines

Tags: svg

I have been searching and was curious if any of you smart guys know how I can join two polylines into one polyline. I could simply create another polyline but would like to join them and I haven't found a polyline command that is like the `Move to` command in Paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is something like that, maybe there are some ways to do that, but I don't think you can ***join two separate Polylines*** with some command. Maybe I'm wrong but I think that the easiest way is to join their points into one *polyline tag*.

**[Here is example](http://jsfiddle.net/8PVSE/1/)**

**Separated polylines:**

```
<svg>
  <polyline points="0 0,100 0" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 3; fill:none;"/>
  <polyline points="100 10,100 100" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 3;fill:none;"/>
</svg>
```

**Мerged polylines:**

```
<svg>
 <polyline points="0 0,100 0 100 10,100 100" style="stroke:black; stroke-width:3;fill:none;"/> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to alter the inherent geometry of the lines the only solution is to use something that is called [''Boolean Operations''](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons).

Boolean operations *cannot* be performed on lines, only on closed shapes that have an area. So if you actually have a rectangle that is lets say 300 x 1 in size it looks like a line and is available to be boolean-operated on.

There is a nice library I've used before called [Javascript Clipper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/) or [Clipper in C++](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php)

In case this is a one time thing you need just use Inkscape or Illustrator (pathfinder window)